# Is there a portable GCC for OS x?

Tags: gcc, gnu, portability

I would love to throw the gcc executable onto my flash drive so that I can compile code in the labs at my school.  Does anyone know of a good, portable, GCC compiler that I could run from the terminal???  I'm using OS x Lion

Answer (score 0):

Sure there is. This would run from command line. But i am sure it can be integrated into IDE too

[gcc for osx](https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer)